# The boy who lived ( Harry Potter book)

Tags: translation

I've  loaded first Harry Potter book, and want to translate it , but first sentence in this book, and I don't know what meaning it have .. Is it about that Harry survived , or it is about some past time which harry had in his life and chapter will be about it ? I mean I don't know what meaning lived has here

Comment: When you say you 'want to translate it', do you just mean you are reading it in the original English? (_Translate_ implies that you are preparing a version in your own language). Harry had survived an attempt to kill him when he was a baby.

Comment: but why author used work live for this ? isn't better to use survive ? when I say translate , I mean I read English version , and try to translate it to my own language

Comment: It was J.K. Rowlings' choice to use _lived_ (did not die). If you are going to get through the whole book, you will just have to accept that every writer expresses themself in their own way.

Comment: @KateBunting Isn't "The boy who lived" the title of the first chapter or section rather than the first line of the text? It's a long time since I read the book. If it is a title then slightly different conventions apply anyway.

Comment: it is a title , and isn't clear,because there is no context about his life , etc .. I know by the movie that Harry survived, but it isn't clear for reader meaning of this work lived , maybe it is about his life at the past @BoldBen

Comment: Obviously, the chapter title refers to something you will come to understand as you read on. You can't expect a title to make its significance plain at the first glance.

Comment: ...and a slightly mysterious title tempts you to read on to find out what it means!

Answer (score 3):

In the Harry Potter stories, when cursed with the 'Killing Curse', A died. B died. C died ... **everybody** died. Except for Harry Potter. *He* is *the Boy who Lived*.

'Live' is used in a rare punctive sense, with the exact meaning of 'survived [this moment of crisis]', here.

Yes, 'survived' is the more obvious choice. But stylistically, and perhaps *because* of the incongruous, dissonant usage, 'lived' wins hands down.

The 'survive a life-and-death moment / crisis' sense *is* seen elsewhere. I'm happy with say

- *Considering the extent of his injuries, it's amazing that he lived.*